# Achieving ZERO fee ethereum transactions like EOS

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, eos

How would Ethereum take on the approach of how EOS have ZERO fees when making a transaction? EOS has the concept of resources, but is there anything like this in the works of "shared resources" for Ethereum? Does the upcoming POS upgrade provide something similar or does GAS Fees always have to play a factor in running smart contracts?

Comment: so, who is making money on EOS then? if it's not by taking transaction fees ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm still learning about other systems. From what it looks like there are no fees, but the miners (block producers) are just guaranteed some type of "reward" to keep the net work up. It definitely is more "centralized" when comparing it to ethereum. But I think that was the intended design in order to make it feeless and fast. I'm not totally 100% sure on that so dont shoot the researcher.

Comment: has NEO witnessed spam attacks yet? Ethereum did. And each spam attack they said thanks to transaction fees, it is a way for users to do not abuse the system. With 0 transaction fees, are they making the system free to use ??? If so, what if abuse by executing tons of smart contracts?

Comment: In EOS, allowed network use (what you call 'resources') is proportional to how much currency a given user holds. This is instead of paying a fee. To launch an attack, a user would have to hold an amount of currency proportional to the bandwidth their attack is using. As far as I can remember, EOS has a set yearly inflation (i.e. issuance) rate, and block producers are directly given part of this as their reward. Not too sure how robust this economic model is.

Comment: Still too new to say. Let's see how it goes a year from now.